# Run a script over multiple datasets

Tags: r

i want to run a script over different datasets. Please see an illustrative example below. I defined a sort of parameters that tells R which dataset to use and how to name output. Now, i would like to have a loop to run the script for all datasets, i.e., first par1 =1 and then par2=1. Could you give some suggetions, please? Thanks in advance.

```
library(MASS)
library(ggplot2)
library(xlsx)  

# Parameters to define which dataset to use: 
  # if i want to use the dataset "beav1", i set par1 to 1 
  # if i want to use the dataset "beav2", i set par2 to 1

  par1 = 1  
  par2 = 0

 if(par1 == 1) {  
  df = beav1        # Load the dataset           
  Name = "beav1"    # Dynamic parameter for plots and output files        
  par1 = 0
 }

  if(par2 == 1){  
    df = beav2       # Load the dataset       
    Name = "beav2"   # Dynamic parameter for plots and output files    
    par2 = 0
  }

  # Make some data manipulation:  
  df = df[,2:3]


  # Plot results:  
  ggplot(df, aes(x=time,temp)) +  
    geom_line() +
    ggtitle(paste0(Name))


  # Save results in xlsx format:  
  write.xlsx(df, paste0(Name, ".xlsx"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is `get`
suppose `beav1` and `beav2` are the dataset you want to use, then you can use them dynamically by

```
data_names <- c("beav1", "beav2")

get(data_names[1]) # give you dataset beav1
get(data_names[2]) # give you dataset beav2
```

Comment: not really. But thanks for your suggestion! i figured it out. i posted my solution below.

Answer (score 0):

i think i figured it out how to implement it. i just put those "parameters" into a dataframe format and run it over a loop.

```
data = data.frame("par1" = 0,"par2" = 0)

for(i in colnames(data)){
    data[i] = 1

if(data[1] == 1){  
  df = beav1        # Load the dataset           
  Name = "beav1"    # Dynamic parameter for plots and output files        
  }

if(data[2] == 1){  
  df = beav2       # Load the dataset       
  Name = "beav2"   # Dynamic parameter for plots and output files    
  }

# Make some data manipulation:  
df = df[,2:3]


# Plot results:  
p=ggplot(df, aes(x=time,temp)) +  
  geom_line() +
  ggtitle(paste0(Name)) +
  ggsave(filename = paste0(Name, ".png"))

save(df,file=paste0(Name, ".Rda"))

 data[i] = 0       # Set the values back to zero 
}
```